# mailto: link for Flutter for Web

Tags: flutter, mailto

The url_launcher package (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) doesn't seem to work for Flutter for Web. The following code prints "test url1" but nothing happens afterwards.

How can I implement `mailto:` like functionality in Flutter for Web which causes the default email app to open with a prepopulated 'to:' email address?

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: _mailto, //() => {},
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  child: _contactBtn(viewportConstraints),
)


  _mailto() async {
    const url = 'mailto:support@email.com?subject=Product Inquiry&body=';
    print("test url1");
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      print("test url2");
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      print("test url3");
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Full helper class that solves this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72030419/1759443

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After experimenting a little I found a way to make **url_launcher** work with web.

Don't use `canLaunch(url)`. Instead, just use `launch(url)`, but wrap it in **try-catch** block. This way you should be safe and the email link will work. For catch you can just copy the email to clipboard and notify the user about that with a snackbar or smth. Probably not the best solution, but a good one, till we get something better.

Here is the sample code, so that you see what I mean:

```
void _launchMailClient(String targetEmail) async {
  String mailUrl = 'mailto:$targetEmail';
  try {
    await launchUrlString(mailUrl);
  } catch (e) {
    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: targetEmail));
  }
}
```

Comment: use `await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "$kEmail"));`

Comment: `launch()` is now deprecated you can use `launchUrlString('mailto:$kEmail')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:mailto/mailto.dart';

// For Flutter applications, you'll most likely want to use
// the url_launcher package.
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

// ...somewhere in your Flutter app...
launchMailto() async {
    final mailtoLink = Mailto(
        to: ['to@example.com'],
        cc: ['cc1@example.com', 'cc2@example.com'],
        subject: 'mailto example subject',
        body: 'mailto example body',
    );
    // Convert the Mailto instance into a string.
    // Use either Dart's string interpolation
    // or the toString() method.
    await launch('$mailtoLink');
}
```