# Flutter-web:url_launcher_web not launching email in browser

Tags: flutter, url, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I've added a feature of sending feedback through email for my flutter web app. This is my code :

```
static void launchEmail(String subjectLine) async {
  const emailId = Constants.ARUDITO_EMAIL;
  print('opening email app for uploading content');
  String url = "mailto:$emailId?subject=$subjectLine";
  if (kIsWeb) {
    if (await webLauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin().canLaunch(url)) {
      await webLauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin().launch(
        url,
        useWebView: true,
        enableDomStorage: true,
        enableJavaScript: true,
        useSafariVC: true,
        webOnlyWindowName: 'Arudito',
        headers: null,
        universalLinksOnly: false,
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open an email app';
    }
  } else {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open an email app';
    }
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml includes :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  url_launcher_web: ^0.1.3+1
```

This code is not launching email in a web browser. It only opens a new tab. However, it is launching on selecting mail app in Windows. Can someone please tell what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact issue. Click on any email link will just opens a new blank tab. That's it.

Took me hours to figure out.

Open `Mail` app on mac, settings, general, and there's an option for default email reader. It was selecting chrome. Change it to a real email client and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I found a [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805244/1339910) in another StackOverflow post.

There it is mentioned that if you just omit the `canLaunch` check and instead wrap the `launch` in a try-catch block it works on Flutter Web. I just tried, and it works nicely.

Btw, there is also a quite new [Link](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/link/Link-class.html) widget in the `url_launcher` package, which makes it possible to create proper web links (including right-click support).